# "ghost" parameter being passed to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have the following test:

```
it 'will pass with valid pageConfig json structure' do 
  document = create(:document, :complete, :belongs_to_user, user_id: @user.id, workspace_id: @workspace.id)
  put :update, params: {id: document.id, pageConfig: {size: {width: 1, height: 1}, margin: {top: 1, bottom: 1, left: 1, right: 1}}, workspace_id: @workspace.id}, as: :json
  expect(document.reload.page_config).to eq({"size": {"width": 1, "height": 1}, "margin": {"top": 1, "left": 1, "right": 1, "bottom": 1}})
end
```

when  debug the `update` endpoint, these are the params:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"pageConfig"=>{"size"=>{"width"=>1, "height"=>1}, "margin"=>{"top"=>1, "bottom"=>1, "left"=>1, "right"=>1}}, "workspace_id"=>1, "id"=>"1", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"documents", "action"=>"update", "document"=>{"workspace_id"=>1}} permitted: false>
```

as you can see, width, height, and workspace_id are all **integer** as they should be but the tests fail due to a validation:

```
Validator of Parameters - Unknown parameter document
```

the last entry on the params is `document =>` which I haven not provided at all.

when I change from `as: :json` to `format: :json`, now the `document` param is gone (which I want) but all other params are parsed as string:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"pageConfig"=>{"margin"=>{"bottom"=>"1", "left"=>"1", "right"=>"1", "top"=>"1"}, "size"=>{"height"=>"1", "width"=>"1"}}, "workspace_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"documents", "action"=>"update"} permitted: false>
```

and now other validations fail because they are a string.

How do I make it work using `as: :json` and make `document` disappear?

I'm using Rails 5.2.0 with RSpec 3.8.0

Comment: What happens if you don't pass `as: :json`?

Comment: the params are sent as String, which fails

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `:as` and `:format` are exclusive? I made some test

```
put '/', params: {id: 1000, pageConfig: {size: {width: 1, height: 1}, margin: {top: 1, bottom: 1, left: 1, right: 1}}, workspace_id: 10001}

{:action=>"/", :controller=>"redacted", :id=>1000, :pageConfig=>{:size=>{:width=>1, :height=>1}, :margin=>{:top=>1, :bottom=>1, :left=>1, :right=>1}}, :workspace_id=>10001}

put '/', params: {id: 1000, pageConfig: {size: {width: 1, height: 1}, margin: {top: 1, bottom: 1, left: 1, right: 1}}, workspace_id: 10001}, as: :json 

{:action=>"/", :controller=>"redacted", :format=>:json, :id=>1000, :pageConfig=>{:size=>{:width=>1, :height=>1}, :margin=>{:top=>1, :bottom=>1, :left=>1, :right=>1}}, :workspace_id=>10001} 

put '/', params: {id: 1000, pageConfig: {size: {width: 1, height: 1}, margin: {top: 1, bottom: 1, left: 1, right: 1}}, workspace_id: 10001}, format: :json  

{:action=>"/", :controller=>"redacted", :format=>:json, :id=>1000, :pageConfig=>{:size=>{:width=>1, :height=>1}, :margin=>{:top=>1, :bottom=>1, :left=>1, :right=>1}}, :workspace_id=>10001}
```

As you can see, I never experience this "ghost" param you have (though I tested on Rails-6.0.0)

I'd suspect some funky gem messing things up for you.

What you can do: start a vanilla rails app, and try to reproduce it. If you can't - this is almost certainly some gems.

If you can - then there's a chance it's a rails bug.